# How to open document by clicking on datagrid in wpf?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have select statement which shows selected items in datagrid.

```
cmdSel.CommandText = "select id,Name,TypeID,StatusID from document where Contains([Context],'FormsOf (INFLECTIONAL, \"" + TextBoxSearch.Text + "\")')";
```

.

```
<WpfToolkit:DataGrid IsTextSearchEnabled="True" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserSortColumns="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="DataGrid1" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MainSearchBinding}" SelectionChanged="DataGrid1_SelectionChanged">              
    <WpfToolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
        <WpfToolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Номер" Width="63" Binding="{Binding id}" IsReadOnly="false" />
        <WpfToolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Название" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="false" />
    </WpfToolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
```

I have another user control with richtextbox. And I want to show that specific data on richtextbox by clicking on datas in datagrid.

I tried what I found here, it did not help me. Please give me direction. Thanks in  advance.

Comment: Where are you stumped at? You have `DataGrid1_SelectionChanged()` method, try updating your `RichTextBox` there. If you have problems with loading data, consider reading http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2010/03/01/wpf-richtextbox-how-to-load-edit-and-save-rich-text-format.aspx

Comment: The problem is how to load specific data into richtextbox. I have user control which has richtextbox. And also I have user control which has datagrid. Datagrid is showing datas which were selected by some criteria. And by clicking to for eaxample ID=15, it should load context of ID=15. I did what you told it is ok. But i have this task now. How to load specific data from datagrid?

Comment: I found decision how to do this, somebody may need it here it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is my answer for my question, somebody may need. Firstly on mouse click I am looking for id and then selecting Context depending on that ID, here is code

```
 private void OnMouseClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {


            IList rows = DataGrid1.SelectedItems;
            DataRowView row = (DataRowView)DataGrid1.SelectedItems[0];
            int a = (int)row["ID"];//It is returning the id of selected row

            DocumentView docview = new DocumentView();

            commProc = new SqlCommand("SELECT Context from Document where ID='" + a + "'", MainWindow.conn);//Depending on ID I am selecting context.
            SqlDataReader dr = commProc.ExecuteReader();
            string str;
            FlowDocument document = new FlowDocument();
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();

            if (dr.Read())
            {
                str = (string)dr["Context"];
                paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run(str)));
                document.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
                docview.RBox.Document = document;

            }

            dr.Close();



            var tabControl = (sender as DataGrid).FindParent<TabControl>();


            tabControl.Items.Add(new TabItem() { Header = "Документ", Content = docview, IsSelected = true });

        }
```